# All of the properties in the Dependent Role can't be Non-Null able

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have this contact Info model.

```
namespace School.Models
{
public partial class ContactInfo
{
    public ContactInfo()
    {
        this.Branches = new List<Branch>();
        this.People = new List<Person>();
    }

    public long ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType( System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DataType.PhoneNumber)]
    [StringLength(12, MinimumLength=9)]
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DataType(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DataType.PhoneNumber)]
    public string CellNumber { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage="Please enter a valid email like name@domain.com")]
    [DataType(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DataType.EmailAddress, ErrorMessage="xyz@domain.com")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Branch> Branches { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Person> People { get; set; }
}
}
```

I have to set all these fields required , But when i do i get an  error that i can't do so. Its working if i remove any one of the required tag but starts giving the error when i make all of them required.
Is there any way that i can set all these fields "Phone Number", "Cell Number", "Email" REQUIRED.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: *What* is the exact error and *when* do you get it (as in: code)?

Comment: @GertArnold
It compiles nicely , no issues there but when i go to the url i.e controller/create i get "All of the properties in the Dependent Role are Null able"

Comment: Please show the involved mappings. This sounds like some contrived foreign key problem.

Comment: Which one ? People or contact Info ? @GertArnold